# AutoCreate in Sencha Touch - why is it required?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've seen this code in the Sencha Touch documentation. If autoCreate was set false what would happen to the infopanel view?  Not sure I understand why autoCreate has to be specified.  Could it not do this behind the scenes anyway if the object type ref is used instead of the simple type?

```
refs: {
    main: '#mainTabPanel',
    loginButton: '#loginWindow button[action=login]',

    infoPanel: {
        selector: 'infopanel',
        xtype: 'infopanel',
        autoCreate: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replaced a few lines of code in one of my project to use `autoCreate`.

This is what I used to do :

```
refs: {
  detailsView: 'detailsview'
},

...

var view = (!this.getDetailsView()) ? Ext.create('App.view.DetailsView') : this.getDetailsView();
nav.push(view);
```

I used to check if the view was created by calling the getter `this.getDetailsView()`. If it was not created, I created it, otherwise I just used the reference to it.

Now, I'm using autoCreate and this is what I do :

```
refs: {
  detailsView: {
    selector: 'detailsview',
    xtype: 'detailsview',
    autoCreate: true
  }
},

...

var view = this.getDetailsView()
nav.push(view);
```

Calling the getter `this.getDetailsView()` will either use the reference to the already created component or create it.

Hope this helps

Comment: So I guess you would set autoCreate to false if you wanted to do something a little different from the norm?

Comment: You don't need to set it to false. Just use a reference with a simple selector then.

Comment: Ok thanks, could they not have got rid of the AutoCreate and not just done it automatically when you create a selector object?